# Office Scripts --> For Loop --> Range Error

Tags: for-loop, range, office-scripts

I am using a for loop to get a range of cells. But when I specify range, it's returning a string. Please help me with this.

Also, I have attached an image of the Error.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  for (let i=0; i<=10; i++)
  {
   var start = 2 + (13 * i);
   var end = 14 + (13 * i);

   var id_start = 'F' + start;
   var id_end = 'BM' + end;
   console.log(id_start)
   console.log(id_end)

   let newrange = 'id_start:id_end';   // Here is Error ---- I need newrange as F2:BM14 
   console.log(newrange)
   workbook.getWorksheet("Emp").getRange(newrange);
  }
}
```

[Image - Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9yn6.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the line of code where you're getting the error

```
let newrange = 'id_start:id_end';
```

You're putting the variables you defined earlier in a string. Instead, you need to keep the variables outside of the string and concatenate them with a string like so:

```
let newrange = id_start + ":" + id_end;
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use template literals, you could write the line like this:

```
let newrange = `${id_start}:${id_end}`
```

Once you update your code to one of those lines it should work.

Comment: Hello Beyphy, Thank you. It works absolutely fine.